# How to print the timestamp on the terminal when user press Enter

Tags: linux, bash, rust, terminal, systemd

First of all I am new to Linux and Rust.

What I am trying to achieve is to print the timestamp to the terminal whenever a user execute a command in the terminal.

I have written a Rust program which will print the current timestamp on the right extreme of the terminal. I was planning to execute this program as `systemd` service in the background using a bash script. What this bash script does is inside an infinite loop, check the key press and if it is **Enter**, then execute the rust program. Before I execute the real Rust program, I just tried to `echo` a string. When I was running the service, I noticed that when I press **Enter**, `echo` runs many times before it stops. I also tried to execute the Rust program instead of the `echo`, but it didn't work the way I imagined. So my solution is wrong smewhere.

My question is, is my approach for this correct? I don't know whether running a background process with an infinite loop is good. This idea I took from the below video.

[Creating systemd Service Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYQBvjYQ63U)

This project is for educational purpose. I was inspired by the [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) project and wanted to understand how it works and do something similar in small scale using Rust.

Could you guys let me know whether this approach is correct or point me to the right direction. Thanks

**main.rs**

```
extern crate termion;
extern crate chrono;


use std::time::SystemTime;
use std::io::stdout;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use termion::{color, terminal_size, cursor, raw::IntoRawMode, cursor::DetectCursorPos};

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
    let cursor_pos = stdout.cursor_pos().expect("Could not get the cursor position");
    let time_now = SystemTime::now();
    let datetime = DateTime::<Utc>::from(time_now);
    let timestamp_str = datetime.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").to_string();
    let size = terminal_size().expect("Could not get the terminal size");
    let x = size.0 - (timestamp_str.len() - 1) as u16;
    let y = cursor_pos.1;
    print!("{}{red}{}{reset}",
        cursor::Goto(x, y),
        timestamp_str,
        red = color::Fg(color::Red),
        reset = color::Fg(color::Reset));
}
```

**bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=

while true
do
    read -n 1 key
    if [ "$key" = "" ]; then
        echo "This was really Enter, not space, tab or something else"
    fi
done
```

**logs from the service**

```
Apr 04 20:49:42 archlinux systemd[1]: Started cmd-timestamp.service.
Apr 04 20:49:42 archlinux cmd-timestamp.sh[410670]: thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code:>
Apr 04 20:49:42 archlinux cmd-timestamp.sh[410670]: note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Apr 04 20:49:42 archlinux systemd[1]: cmd-timestamp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=101/n/a
Apr 04 20:49:42 archlinux systemd[1]: cmd-timestamp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: I don't think Powerline use systemd feature at all.

Comment: I come from a web development background. Therefore I don't have any experience related to this kind of system programming. I tried to find any guide which points to the right direction but I couldn't find. That is why posted here. So you know any other way which I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I fully understand what you're trying to achieve.  If you're talking about printing a time-stamp each time the uses uses bash interactively, e.g. doing an `ls` or some other program/script that runs non-interactively, the easiest way would be to use your program as bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  Responding to each and every press of ENTER by running it as a service hooked deeply into the system seems like a dead-sure way to screw up your terminal ...

Comment: @tink This great. Thanks. I think I can use this to execute my rust app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the comment to the answer section:

The easiest way to accomplish what I think you want is to hook your program into bash via the `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

In your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_login`) set:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=/path/to/rust/executable
```

Comment: Is `export` necessary ?

Comment: @Philippe - feel free to experiment and come back with your findings. My understanding is that `export`ing makes the variable accessible to any spawned subshell ...

Comment: What I actually used in `~/.bashrc` is `CMD_TIMESTAMP=/path/to/rust/executable` `PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"; "$CMD_TIMESTAMP` This works for me

Comment: @tink, When we have `PROMPT_COMMAND=/path/to/rust/executable` in `~/.bashrc`, we have the effect anyway (in subshell as well), without `export`. I can't see a need in OP to require we pass the variable to spawned subshell.